# Mono executes program with wrong current directory

Tags: c#, linux, path, mono, raspberry-pi

I have a strange problem. I have written a custom spamfilter in C# .NET 4.6 for personal use. And I put this program up to my Raspberry Pi.

I have tested many times the program, and everything worked fine, but when I created a cronjob I have noticed that the program never writes log.

As I started to test again I have find out, that the problem is, when I start the program from the program's base dir, it works fine:

```
> cd path/to/program
> mono program.exe
```

but when I start it from another directory with absolute path:

```
> mono /absolute/path/to/program/program.exe
```

The required files' relative paths go wrong.

For example if I'm in the /home directory, and my program is in /home/user/program directory, and I run this:

```
> mono /home/user/program/program.exe
```

I get " Could not find file "/home/xyz.txt" "

I have tried to create absolute paths from relative paths in the program using `Path.GetFullPath()` and `Environment.CurrentDirectory` but nothing changed.

So my question is: Is there any option to run a mono program in another directory with correct current directory?

I know that a bash script could execute my first solution (cd and then mono) and it could be used in cron, but I want to know if there is a simplier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current directory is *correct*, it is the current directory of where you are *starting* the process, and that process is `mono` in this case, and *not* the location of the CIL-based assembly that mono is loading.

What it sounds like you want is the path of the `ExecutingAssembly`.

This works on x-plat (Windows/Linux/macOS):

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
Console.WriteLine(path);
```

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx

Comment: Thank you! This is what I looking for.